# Does MinGW-w64 g++ expose microsoft ucrt's implementation of C11 `getenv_s` function? If yes, what header to be included?

Tags: c++, mingw, c++17, mingw-w64, c11

According to cppreference.com, getenv_s gets supported since [C11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv)

```
errno_t getenv_s( size_t *restrict len, char *restrict value,
                  rsize_t valuesz, const char *restrict name );
```

With [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) 8.1, g++ reports an error with both `#include` with `cstdlib` and `stdlib.h`

```
use of undeclared identifier 'getenv_s'; did you mean '_wgetenv_s'?
    errcode = getenv_s(&envsize, NULL, 0, name);
              ^~~~~~~~
              _wgetenv_s
```

I wonder why MinGW-w64 g++ seems not to expose microsoft ucrt's C11 [getenv_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-s-wgetenv-s)?

In c++, do we already have a ***portable*** way to retrieve environment variables safely?

Comment: [`getenv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) ?

Comment: @user463035818 Do you think when retrieving an environment variable, there is no need to be copied explicitly like in C11 `getenv_s`?

Comment: not sure what you mean exactly with "copied explicitly", so no i dont think so ;). You are worried by `getenv` returning a raw pointer?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages

Comment: Currently `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>` includes `<stdlib.h>` rather than the other way around since Microsoft's "Secure CRT" API is optional rather than required in mingw-w64, so it's "opt-in" by including the appropriate implementation-specific header. As a result, using `<cstdlib>` in C++ won't include the secure functions, and you'll need to include the implementation-specific `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>` for the secure versions of the functions normally declared in C's `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune For future readers' sake, would you mind pasting above as an answer. I will make it as accepted. Thank you for the finding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

The originally amended answer below is not entirely correct.  Currently there is no declaration for `getenv_s` in `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>` on MinGW-w64 implementations, but you can declare it yourself:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <sec_api/stdlib_s.h> /* errno_t, size_t */
errno_t getenv_s(
    size_t     *ret_required_buf_size,
    char       *buf,
    size_t      buf_size_in_bytes,
    const char *name
);

/*
 * You can omit this section if you don't want to use the safer
 * C++ template function in your C++ code.
 */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C++" {
  template <size_t size>
  getenv_s(
      size_t *ret_required_buf_size,
      char (&buf)[size],
      const char *name
  ) { return getenv_s(ret_required_buf_size, buf, size, name); }
}
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

On MSVC, you'd still just use `#include <stdlib.h>` as `getenv_s` is declared there.

There are also several other C++ template functions missing from the `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>` already, presumably due to lack of need, and the lack of declaration for `getenv_s` entirely is perhaps just something nobody needed as `getenv` worked just fine.

It's worth mentioning that there is [a Windows-only function called `_dupenv_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/dupenv-s-wdupenv-s) that is much easier to use in place of `getenv_s`, and you'd just free the memory using the standard `free` function.  It is declared in `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>`, so you can use it without issue.

---

**Amended original answer:**

At the time of this answer, MinGW-w64 built from source allows you to enable or disable the exposure of the secure CRT functions by default, but even when enabled, it does not appear to mark most standard C functions with secure replacements as "deprecated" the way that Visual C++'s CRT headers do (actually, it appears that it does mark some of them as deprecated, but the macros expand to nothing in the build I'm using).

To more directly address the question, the MinGW-w64 implementation currently stores the prototypes for the secure CRT functions in a separate header file in the `sec_api` directory, and that header file is not included from the standard C header, which means the corresponding C++ header `<cstdlib>` will not declare the functions either since it includes only the standard header.

Instead, you need to explicitly include the C headers you need such as `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>`, `<sec_api/stdio_s.h>`, etc., which will only declare the functions if the secure API has been enabled (i.e. `MINGW_HAS_SECURE_API` is defined to 1 in `_mingw.h`).  As the functions are likely available for linking, you can just use `#define MINGW_HAS_SECURE_API 1` before any includes to enable the use of the secure functions that are declared, or declare the functions yourself in the event that they're undeclared.

I feel it's worth mentioning that many, though not all, of the C++-only template functions such as

```
// #include <sec_api/string_s.h> in MinGW-w64.
// #include <string.h> (C) or <cstring> (C++) in MSVC.
template <size_t size>
errno_t strcpy_s(
    char      (&dest)[size],
    const char *src
);
```

are declared and implemented.

Based on [examples in Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s#example) and preprocessor output in the case of MinGW-w64, both implementations place the secure functions in the global C++ namespace, not the `std` namespace (e.g. `strcpy_s` in its fully qualified form is `::strcpy_s`) as they're not standard C++ functions.

Comment: I just found out that there is no getenv_s even in <sec_api/stdlib_s.h>, but you can declare on your [***own***](https://git.uwaterloo.ca/nguenthe/statasvm/blob/master/src/_svm_setenv.c) anyway. Like mingw32 encourage _dupenv_s instead. Please investigate further to confirm this hypothesis and edit your answer.

Comment: @sandthorn I've updated my answer with some fixes. Out of curiosity, do you have a reference for your statement _"mingw32 encourage `_dupenv_s` instead"_?

Comment: Sorry, I have no reference about that. However if you peek into `<sec_api/stdlib_s.h>`, there is only one safe platform api there, that is `_dupenv_s`. While MSVC itself allows c++ code use c11 `getevn_s` api that other c++ compiler [***doesn't***](https://godbolt.org/z/R9_9bY) allow. So I guess MinGW-w64 are trying to preserve that ***portal*** behavior and end up with exposing win32 specific api `_dupenv_s` instead.

Comment: @sandthorn You keep writing "C11", but the fact is that any interest in the 
 `_s` functions is limited in the C world. MSVC provides those functions, but it's not a C11-compliant compiler because MSVC uses an "invalid parameter handler" with a different function signature than C11's "runtime-constraint handler" (e.g. [`set_constraint_handler_s` and `constraint_handler_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/set_constraint_handler_s) don't exist in MSVC; it uses [`_set_invalid_parameter_handler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb.aspx) instead).

Comment: (continued) If anything, `getenv_s` is "portable" in that it will work with any Windows compiler that relies upon the MSVCRT C runtime library like MinGW-w64 does. The lack of a `getenv_s` declaration in the header file is probably just an oversight as the function still works properly if you provide a declaration before its use because MinGW-w64 uses MSVCRT. [The optional bounds-checking API of C11 is still controversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)#Criticism) and [its removal has been proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#tc).

Comment: Thank for point out the differences between C11 and MSVC. One more thing, I wonder why even *optional* bound-check api are so hard to get into (and/or remain as) standard? Is it because everybody wants some kind of zero-breaking-change solution that is impossible for now?

Comment: @sandthorn The bounds-checking API is very effective, but it means a lot of runtime checks **every time the program is executed.** Instead, these checks should be done at testing time using tools like those listed in the ["Alternatives" section of my last link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#alternatives), so the performance hit is minimal. The last link also summarizes the reasons discussed in the report above that section before concluding the feature should be removed, but if you want more info, just browse through the sections that interest you.

Comment: "*Instead, these checks should be done at testing time*" Eh? Even though, that's very convincing, sometimes some "*runtime input*" should also be bound-checked "***at runtime***" anyway? If yes, how come safe api become less useful?

Comment: @sandthorn _"Runtime input"_ should indeed be carefully handled, but the safe API just gets in the way. `gets_s` for example will completely ignore a line that you enter if the buffer size you specify is too small, unlike `fgets`. Supposing you have input already, `strtok_s` doesn't do anything more useful than `strtok` except that it allows you to specify a pointer for it to continue its work instead of using a hidden pointer, making it reentrant (it's basically POSIX `strtok_r` with NULL pointer checks). `strcpy_s` is basically `strlcpy`, except you get an error when truncation would occur.

Comment: (continued) Also, suppose you accidentally didn't update the size of a buffer after shrinking the buffer; the safe API won't protect you from accidents like that whereas some tools like Valgrind allow you to test for this without you needing to write the tests yourself.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. `_s` turn out to be some kind of misleading because of their own names. Removing of Annex K, if it happens, this means using `_s` should be avoided if ones can?

Comment: @sandthorn Unless you're writing code targeting a platform that supports those functions or a project's standards require you to use those functions when possible, the functions should be avoided. Defining the preprocessor macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` will prevent a compiler targeting Windows from emitting diagnostics that encourage the use of the `_s` functions in place of their counterparts without the suffix.

Comment: Aside: I'd even say that Microsoft's overloading of the names to create the less error-prone C++ template functions are only useful for fixed-length arrays. `const char *hello = "Hello, world!"; char* buf = new char[32]; strcpy_s(buf, "Hello, world!");` doesn't compile because `buf` is a pointer, not an array, so you need to resort to code like `strcpy_s(cast<32>(buf), hello);`. The implementation of `cast` is unimportant, but notice how you specified 32 again; you should have just used `strcpy_s(buf, 32, hello);`. `char buf[32]; strcpy_s(buf, hello);` works fine with no cast needed though!

Comment: MSYS2 now has getenv_s. You need to include #include <sec_api/stdlib_s.h> of course

Answer (score 4):

> In c++, do we already have a portable way to retrieve environment variables safely?

You can use `getenv`. If don't want to have a raw pointer to a C string owned by someone else leaking into your code you can use `std::optional`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <optional>
std::optional<std::string> get_env(const char* env) {
    auto t = std::getenv(env);
    if (t) return t;
    return {};
}
```

[Full example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/snmrjjBjaOCXrhtn).

PS: even if it was available in C++, I am not sure if I would use `getenv_s`. `resitrct` is not standard C++, and passing arrays and their size seperately isnt very idiomatic C++. To my understanding `getenv_s` is an improvement to `getenv` in C where you need to deal with nullpointers and string lenghts somehow while in C++ we have different solutions available (`std::string` for variable length strings and `std::optional` for optional values).

Comment: Regarding the "an improvement to `getenv`" note, yes, all of the `_s` functions made available in C11's optional "Bounds-checking interfaces" section (Annex K) were intended to be improvements. From the website OP linked: _Another call to `getenv` ... may invalidate the pointer returned by a previous call ..._ `getenv_s` was added to C to solve that problem by obtaining a local copy of the value using the provided buffer and buffer size.

Comment: And for Windows specifically, MSVC also provides `template <size_t size> errno_t getenv_s(size_t *len, char (&buffer)[size], const char *varname);` for C++. C++/CLI code could instead use the [static member function `GetEnvironmentVariable` that belongs to the `System::Environment` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Environment_GetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_).